# timer_getoverrun() doesn't behave as expected when using sleep()

Tags: c, linux, signals

Here is a program that uses a POSIX per-process timer alongside the `sleep()` subroutine. The signal sent when the timer expires has been set to `SIGUSR1` rather than `SIGALRM`, since `SIGALRM` may be used internally by `sleep()`, but it still doesn't seem to work.

I have run the program using the command line `timer-overruns -d 1 -n 10000000` (1 cs interval) so, in theory, we should expect 100 overruns between calls to `sigwaitinfo()`. However, `timer_getoverrun()` returns 0.

I have also tried a version using a time-consuming `for` loop to introduce the delay. In this case, overruns **are** recorded.

Does anyone know why this happens? I am running a 3.4 Linux kernel.

## Program source

```
/*
 * timer-overruns.c
 */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

// Signal to be used for timer expirations
#define TIMER_SIGNAL SIGUSR1

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int opt;
    int d = 0;
    int r = 0; // Repeat indefinitely
    struct itimerspec its;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    // Parse arguments
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "d:r:s:n:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'd': // Delay before calling sigwaitinfo()
            d = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'r': // Number of times to call sigwaitinfo()
            r = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 's': // Timer interval (seconds)
            its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'n': // Timer interval (nanoseconds)
            its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default: /* '?' */
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Usage: %s [-d signal_accept_delay] [-r repetitions] [-s interval_seconds] [-n interval_nanoseconds]\n",
                    argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // Check sanity of command line arguments
    short e = 0;

    if (d < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Delay (-d) cannot be negative!\n");
        e++;
    }
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of repetitions (-r) cannot be negative!\n");
        e++;
    }
    if (its.it_interval.tv_sec < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Interval seconds value (-s) cannot be negative!\n");
        e++;
    }
    if (its.it_interval.tv_nsec < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Interval nanoseconds value (-n) cannot be negative!\n");
        e++;
    }
    if (its.it_interval.tv_nsec > 999999999) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Interval nanoseconds value (-n) must be < 1 second.\n");
        e++;
    }

    if (e > 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // Set default values if not specified
    if (its.it_interval.tv_sec == 0 && its.it_interval.tv_nsec == 0) {
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    }

    printf("Running with timer delay %d.%09d seconds\n",
            (int) its.it_interval.tv_sec, (int) its.it_interval.tv_nsec);

    // Will be waiting for signals synchronously, so block the one in use.  
    sigset_t sigset;

    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, TIMER_SIGNAL);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL );

    // Create and arm the timer
    struct sigevent sev;
    timer_t timer;

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = TIMER_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timer;

    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timer);
    timer_settime(timer, TIMER_ABSTIME, &its, NULL );

    // Signal handling loop
    int overruns;
    siginfo_t si;

    // Make the loop infinite if r = 0
    if (r == 0)
        r = -1;

    while (r != 0) {
        // Sleeping should cause overruns
        if (d > 0)
            sleep(d);

        sigwaitinfo(&sigset, &si);

        // Check that the signal is from the timer
        if (si.si_code != SI_TIMER)
            continue;

        overruns = timer_getoverrun(timer);
        if (overruns > 0) {
            printf("Timer overrun occurred for %d expirations.\n", overruns);
        }

        // Decrement r if not repeating indefinitely
        if (r > 0)
            r--;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the cause, but I'm also not sure your usage is valid. It seems to me there are inherent race conditions using `timer_getoverrun` with `sigwaitinfo` instead of a signal handler, and so perhaps it does not even work correctly except when called from the signal handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fail to set `its.it_value.tv_sec` when only nanoseconds are set, i.e. `-n 10000000` but no `-s 0`. Properly initialize `its.it_value`, or use `-s 0` parameter, and your code should work -- after a fashion.

Due to `sigemptyset(&sigset); sigaddset(&sigset, TIMER_SIGNAL); sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);` I do not think there is a race condition, `sigwaitinfo()` should reliably obtain the pending signal. Check the [sigwaitinfo()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) man page for details; it does describe this very same use case in the Notes section.

It seems that the value returned by [timer_getoverrun()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_getoverrun.2.html) the first time after the timer fires, is bogus, at least on a 3.5.0 kernel on an x86-64. In other words, adding this just before the loop,

```
    printf("Overruns: %d\n",
           timer_getoverrun(timer));
    sigwaitinfo(&sigset, &si);
    printf("Overruns: %d (%d)\n",
           timer_getoverrun(timer), si.si_overrun);
    sigwaitinfo(&sigset, &si);
    printf("Overruns: %d (%d)\n",
           timer_getoverrun(timer), si.si_overrun);
```

will output zero, a seemingly random overrun count, then the expected overrun count. (Both timer and siginfo overrun counts do match.) I suspect there is a problem in [kernel/posix-timers.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/posix-timers.c;hb=HEAD), but I might be wrong.. the problem seems to be that the first timer event will use a random value for the previous overrun count. I think I'll investigate that further.

I would appreciate it a lot if you could tell me whether you see the same on your kernel. (Please also state the exact version and architecture. I'm running Ubuntu linux-image-3.5.0-3-generic, version 3.5.0-3.3, on amd64 (x86-64).

Comment: Good spot. It does indeed work as expected when `its.it_value.tv_sec` is properly intialised. As for the bogus value: this is because the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag is set when calling `timer_settime`, but the clock's value is undefined. I should really have stripped this out for the test case to avoid confusion.

Comment: I somehow missed that! The `timer_settime()` man page does clearly state that the in this case, *if the specified absolute time has already passed, then the timer expires immediately, and the overrun count will be set* correctly. In other words, to reflect the number of expirations since that past time that *would have happened*. The reason I suspected a kernel bug is that the currently active overrun count is split into two fields, `.it_overrun` and `.it_overrun_last`, which happen to be initialized in different functions. Well, we all make mistakes, don't we ;)

Comment: I suspected a kernel bug, too, until you pointed out that my code was broken. This would have been nice, actually, since I'm trying to analyse an audio/video skipping issue. One of the things I suspect is a timing issue. Ah, well, keep digging...